# Can not navigate to Outlook add-in submission page after review

Tags: outlook, office-addins

I submitted our company Outlook add-in and received a review email asking for corrections. I saved the URL of the submission page https://partner.microsoft.com/en-us/dashboard/office/products/ce33a138-e74c-4db2-a241-47f05ef4f9c7/packages before submitting the add-on. This is that page:

[image]

If I log in now to I can no longer open this page and see the default page instead https://partner.microsoft.com/en-US/dashboard/directory

It is hard to believe that Microsoft requires a brand new add-on submission with all icons and screenshots to be added again. I definitely use the same Microsoft account - we have one company account associated with an email group in our company.

Both links in the Microsoft review email lead to https://partner.microsoft.com/en-US/dashboard/support where I see

> "You don’t have access.
>
> You don’t have permission to view this page. Contact your account
> admin for access. Learn how to manage permissions."

The submission process was way easier and way friendlier compared to doing the same with submitting Google add-in until this point where I literally lost access to all hard work already done and can not move forward.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be contacting the support team for Partner Center and they can help you here. Please start from here https://partner.microsoft.com/en-US/support/v2/?stage=1
I hope you will be getting the answer what you are looking for.

Thanks,

Jeevan Desarda

Comment: Unfortunately, it is the same page I described: "You don’t have access. You don’t have permission to view this page. Contact your account admin for access. Learn how to manage permissions.
Sign-in with another account" and I have only one account the one I used to submit application.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I am sure I used account type (1) to submit the application for a review I finally tried to use (2) and was able to access my application submission again. I was able to resubmit it with corrections being made based on the MSFT team feedback.

[![Microsoft account type selector][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSaLb.png